# Duplicate tags [typeahead.js] and [twitter-typeahead]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[typeahead.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeahead.js) and [twitter-typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-typeahead) are about the same thing. The latter is less used.

Comment: They appear to be about different things.  Having different tags for even different forks of the same project isn't necessarily a bad thing. Are they the same thing??

Comment: @Will As far as I know they are about the same thing. There is [tag:bootstrap-typeahead], too, but that's something different.

Comment: Almost half of the `twitter-typeahead` tagged questions are also tagged `typeahead.js`.  From the descriptions, they refer to the same library.